# Another htaccess question ... Recursive RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to apply a rewrite rule to all images within a certain directory.  I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/source/([a-zA-Z-_]+).(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ /files/$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

But, it doesn't seem to affect images within subdirectories of the files folder?  (i.e., files/image.gif, files/8994/image2.png, files/subproject/3349/image3.jpg, should all be affected.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^source/([a-zA-Z-_\/\.]+).(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$   files/$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

Remember DO NOT PUT `/` in beginning of RewriteRule!(e.g  `source/`  NOT `/source/`)

**edit:**

it will rewrite `source/ajsbdkjasd.aksjdbf/asldkjbfaskdf.gif` to `files/ajsbdkjasd.aksjdbf/asldkjbfaskdf.gif`!

```
RewriteRule ^source/([a-zA-Z-_\/\.]+).(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$   files/$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the suggested edits, but it still shows the real path (i.e., files/image.gif) rather than source/image.gif

Comment: @Scooter5150  your real file is in source or files directory?

Comment: @Scooter5150 do you want to do that with sub-directories within files directory? I mean you want to rewrite /source/bubble/01.gif to /files/bubble/01.gif?

Comment: No, vice versa... The real file is in files/ and the fake path is in source/  Did I get it mixed up?